# searching for <beginningOfLine><Comma>

Tags: regular-expressions, isearch

how can I (interactive) search for `<beginningOfLine>,`

I tried ^ which means beginning of line in perl
Also \A which does signified the same in ruby.

C-s ^,
C-s \A,

I also tried search-forward-regexp with above.

```
# /tmp/routes.txt
1,GET    /clients/:client_id/committees/:id,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,GET    /clients/:client_id/committees/:id/edit,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,GET    /clients/:client_id/committees/new,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,POST   /clients/:client_id/committees,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,GET    /clients/:client_id/committees,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: C-u C-s to call isearch-forward-regexp, use "^,"

Comment: gold! thanks for that

Comment: I suspect that this is a duplicate - but if not, then @nichijou's comment should be made into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isearch-forward-regexp`. Its binding is `C-M-s`, you can also invoke it with `C-u C-s`.

[The regexp Emacs used for line beginning](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#index-beginning-of-line-in-regexp) is `^`.